# Series Expansion of $\frac{1}{(x+a)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Is there a simple series expansion for:
$$ \frac{1}{(x+a)^n}$$
Where $|a| < x$ and $x \in \Bbb R^+$

I am interested in a one that does not contain the $(x+a)^n$.

Comment: Just use the Taylor development around $x=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Difficult to consider that $x\to0$ when one is said that $x>|a|$, presumably for some fixed nonzero $a$.

Comment: @Did: that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x| < |a|$,
$\frac1{(a+x)^n}
=\frac1{a^n(1+x/a)^n}
=\frac1{a^n}(1+x/a)^{-n}
=\frac1{a^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-n}{k}\left(\frac{x}{a} \right)^k
$

If $|x| > |a|$,
$\frac1{(a+x)^n}
=\frac1{x^n(1+a/x)^n}
=\frac1{x^n}(1+a/x)^{-n}
=\frac1{x^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 
\binom{-n}{k}\left(\frac{a}{x} \right)^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 
\binom{-n}{k}\frac{a^k}{x^{n+k}}
$

If you want, you can apply
$\binom{-n}{k}
=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}
$.

Answer (score -1):

HINT:

Write it as

$$(x + a)^{-n}$$

and use Binomial expansion.

**More**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

To understand the two cases in which $|x| > |a|$ and $|x| < |a|$ just read the answer above!

Comment: One needs at least some normalization to get a convergent expansion.

Comment: That is true, one should indeed check about how much is $x$, like $|x| < 1$ for example..

Comment: No--the problem is the condition $x>|a|$, which your post omits completely.

Comment: @Did Right!! Well.. I was going to but seems like the other user just did it!